# Change View Text Color by code

Tags: android, view

Well, I developed a menu with eight Buttons for an App. So, every time the user clicks on in one of the buttons, such button changes its background. And I would would like to change its color as well. But I got now idea how, since setTextColor does not work with Views.

I'm using View because its part of onClick method that I override in order to achieve what I want. So, here go the code:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.degrade_menu);

    }
```

So, how could I change the text color?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast your `v` to TextView and then set the text color. Do not forget to read color from resourse

```
((TextView)v).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.errorColor));
```

Answer (score 0):

quick solution:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(<id>);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button.setTextColor(<color>);
    }
};
```

better solution: use [states](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html)

Comment: Why keep a reference when you can just cast the view to a button?

Answer (score 0):

Cast the view to a button. Then you can use settextcolor